# Configure NetBeans 7.3.1 to allow java files in Projects, but not compile them

Tags: java, netbeans

The company I am working for is using a third party tool which relies upon "base" files with multiple implementations inside of them.  The tool then preprocesses the files to generate the production files.

The problem is that with an IDE and java files, when there are two classes with the same name, the IDE reports a conflict.  Further, since the base file has a different name than the java class, there is an error that the class should be in a file that matches its name.

Luckily, the base files are all in dotted directories - directories which start with dot - making them effectively invisible, unless requested to see them.

**The goal is to have the dotted directories visible in the IDE, but the contents ignored by the IDE when it comes to compilation (though it would be great to have the ctrl-click abilities).**

I am able to accomplish this in Eclipse by allowing my Package Explorer to see .*resources and configure the excludes for the project to include **/.*/**.

With NetBeans, I can update the regex for the Ignored Files (Options/Miscellaneous/Files) to not exclude the dotted directories.  This brings all the contents into the IDE, adding them as compilation units.  So, I tried using the Excludes for the project via Project Properties/Sources/"Includes/Exclude".  However, this results in removing the units from the IDE as was previously done with the regex.

**How can I configure NetBeans to allow the elements into the IDE, but to ignore them as compilation units so as to not have errors/actions reported in the IDE?**

Using another tool is not an option, nor is not using the tool and creating a different design.

This must be accomplished with NetBeans 7.3.1 or 7.1 with the third party tool.

Comment: Did you try an up-to-date Version of NetBeans? 7.3. is pretty old

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unfortunately I am stuck with the tools given to me.  And worse, I may have to go back to Netbeans 7.1.